# Using BigDecimal correctly

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

I'm doing scientific calculations that need to be accurate as possible so I am converting the existing use of `Double` to `BigDecimal`.

```
// before
double tmp = x - (y / z);

// after
BigDecimal tmp = new BigDecimal(
        x.value().subtract(y.value().divide(z.value())).toString());
```

Is this logical or what?

Comment: What are the types of x,y,z?

Comment: Their types are doubles

Comment: Don't use doubles, just use strings. `x = new BigDecimal("1.2")` etc for y and z. Then just use them directly. The precision for double is already lost when you type it into your program, so passing it to BigDecimal doesn't gain anything.

Comment: how can you use x.value() then if it is a primitive type?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing your arithmetics with doubles before converting the result to BigDecimal. That way you don't gain any precision.

You should convert every number to BigDecimal as soon as possible and then use the methods of BigDecimals (subtract, divide and so on) on the BigDecimal representation to do the arithmetics.

```
BigDecimal bdX = new BigDecimal(x);
BigDecimal bdY = new BigDecimal(y);
BigDecimal bdZ = new BigDecimal(z);

BigDecimal tmp = bdX.subtract(bdY.divide(bdZ));
```

Answer (score 2):

`BigDecimal` has methods for all the operators. You should use them instead. You can also control (specify) the scale and rounding.

Avoid using doulbles, instead use `BigDecimal` from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that x, y and z are doubles

```
BigDecimal tmp = new BigDecimal(x).subtract(
           new BigDecimal(y).divide(new BigDecimal(z), MathContext.DECIMAL64));
```

see BigDecimal.divide API to understand why to use MathContext